# empty screen when connecting to openEdx

Tags: docker, openedx

I've set up tutor on a separate machine and have port 80 open for connection.

While running the docker containers I get the *_permissions of the containers fails - is this normal?

I then open the web up and I just have a blank screen. Caddy logs my attempts to connect but still nothing starts. what could be the problem?

Comment: Are you running tutor as local or dev? If it's dev you have to check on port 8000. if not check the LMS logs also. And what do you mean by "*_permissions of the containers fail". If nothing works, start fresh, there is a guideline for that also.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was fiddling around for a while :(

I'm not sure if we have the same initial situation, but I'd like to remarks some points, that helped me to find my solution:

1. The blank page is the [default behavior of 'caddy'](https://caddy.community/t/caddy-returns-blank-page-always/14020). So it is correct what you see in the logs...caddy reacts and delivers the blank page.
2. I noticed, that there is absolutely nothing else logged for `tutor local logs -f`...only entries of caddy. So this means my request was not forwarded to to the lms or cms...because otherwise, there should be logs from `tutor_local-cms-1` or `tutor_local-lms-1` But why?
3. My problem was, that the header information of the request for `Host` did not fit to the expected `Host`.

   - I have a proxy from a central nginx-instance...this listens to something like `cms.my.domain.com` & `lms.my.domain.com.
   - This has to be to the entry in the config.yml...clear!
   - But I forgot to tell nginx to forward that info by: `proxy_set_header Host $host;`